# Probability of drawing unknown color at the beginning and at the end of nth draw

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not sure how to handle the unknown color situation. If the color of the first ball was known then I would have tried in a way (showing below, not sure I am correct but that's my initial approach.

**Actual question:**
You have 4 red balls, 8 green balls, and 10 purple balls. You draw a ball from the bag, record its color. Continue drawing without replacement until you get a ball that matches the color of the first ball. What is the probability that it takes exactly 3 additional draws (not including draw 0) to get a matching ball?

Say I knew the color and it was red then (again, I could be wrong):

pr = (8+10)/(4+8+10-1) * (8+10-1)/(4+8+10-2) * (3/(4+8+10-3))

I really appreciate any direction/explanation that anyone can provide

Comment: Hint: I guess you can do similar computations for green and purple, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be efficient but:

The probability of the first ball being Red is $\frac 4{22}$.  If the first ball is red the probability of the next two not being red is $\frac {18*17}{21*20}$ and if that happens the probability of the fourth ball being red is $\frac 3{19}$.  So the probability of the first ball being red and my getting a second red ball exactly three balls later is $\frac 4{22}\frac {18*17}{21*20}\frac 3{19}$.

Doing the same for if the first ball is green we can $\frac 8{22}$ and then $\frac {14*13}{21*20}$ and $\frac 7{19}$.  So the prob of that is $\frac {8*14*13*7}{22*...*19}$.

And for the first ball being purple we have $\frac {10}{22}\frac {12*11}{21*20}\frac 9{19}$

So the probability is

$\frac {4*18*17*3}{22*...*19} + \frac{8*14*13*7}{22*..*19}+ \frac {10*12*11*9}{22*...*19}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the first ball was red.  This occurs with probability $\frac{4}{22}$ as there are $4$ red balls out of $4+8+10=22$ balls total.

Given that the first ball was red, in order for the fourth ball to be the first re-occurrence of a red ball, that means that the next two draws must both be non-red.  As such the second ball being non-red given that the first is red will occur with probability $\frac{18}{21}$, and given that the first is red and second is non-red the third ball also being non-red will occur with probability $\frac{17}{20}$.  Finally, given the first is red and the next two are non-red the probability that the fourth ball is red will be $\frac{3}{19}$

This gives the probability that the first is red and the first re-occurrence of red occurs on the fourth draw as being $\frac{4}{22}\times\frac{18}{21}\times\frac{17}{20}\times\frac{3}{19}$

Continue in the same fashion for if the first ball happened to be green or purple and add the results.